# Rails 6 : I can't install tailwind

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node-modules, tailwind-css, webpacker

I'm trying to install Tailwind CSS 2.0 in a RoR 6.1.3 and Ruby 2.7.2 application. I'm just not seeing any update to the styling in the output on localhost and get any error unless with bin/webpack :

> ERROR in ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
> (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--5-2!./app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)
> Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
> Error: Failed to find 'tailwindcss/base'   in [
> ...../app/assets/stylesheets   ]
> at ..../node_modules/postcss-import/lib/resolve-id.js:35:13  @ ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.css 2:26-171  @
> ./app/javascript/packs/application.js

**app/javascript/packs/application.js**

```
import '../utils/direct_uploads.js';
ActiveStorage.start()
require("../../assets/stylesheets/application.css")
```

**package.json**

```
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.6.0",
    "@rails/actiontext": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "5.2.1",
    "@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat": "^2.0.4",
    "activestorage": "^5.2.3",
    "autoprefixer": "^9",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "gmaps": "^0.4.24",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.0",
    "leaflet": "^1.4.0",
    "lodash.debounce": "^4.0.8",
    "postcss": "^7",
    "postcss-cssnext": "^3.1.0",
    "stimulus": "2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat",
    "trix": "^1.0.0"
  },
```

**/postcss.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('tailwindcss')('./tailwind.config.js'),
    require('autoprefixer'),
    require('postcss-import'),
    require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
    require('postcss-preset-env')({
      autoprefixer: {
        flexbox: 'no-2009'
      },
      stage: 3
    })
  ]
}
```

**app/assets/stylesheets/application.css**

```
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
```

**application.html.erb**

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>     
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all' %>     
<%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all' %>
```

On the test page I get theses errors :

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/tailwindcss/base"):
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/tailwindcss/components"):
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/tailwindcss/utilities"):
```

How can I fix it ?

Comment: Try import("../../assets/stylesheets/application.css")

Comment: No, I always have the same error :(

Comment: Are you using webpacker? css from packs need to be loaded with stylesheet_pack_tag.

Comment: Yes in my application.html.erb I have :

    ```<%= javascript_pack_tag 'application' %>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all' %>
    <%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all' %>```

Comment: Keep just the one with stylesheet pack tag. stylesheet_link_tag is for asset pipeline.

Comment: No, It's always the same

Comment: show webpack.config.js please

Answer (score 0):

Does importing your postcss plugins like this fix your problem?

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
    ...
  },
}
```